# Crontab cron job not creating the redirected output file

Tags: cron

I have configured crontab to have the following entry:

```
*/2 * * * * source /home/ubuntu/cronenv/python2.7/bin/activate && python /home/ubuntu/trial.py  >> /var/log/mycron/trial.log 2>&1 && deactivate
```

By tailing the /var/log/syslog file, I can verify that the cron runs every two minutes. This is the entry in /var/log/syslog every two minutes

```
Nov  8 10:52:01 ip-172-31-0-41 CRON[2023]: (ubuntu) CMD (source /home/ubuntu/cronenv/python2.7/bin/activate && python /home/ubuntu/trial.py  >> /var/log/mycron/trial.log 2>&1 && deactivate)
```

By running the command in terminal, it runs as intended and creates **trial.log** file in **/var/log/mycron/**

The folder has all the required permissions as shown below:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root     4096 Nov  8 11:02 mycron
```

Please help me in figuring out the issue.

Comment: You are missing the `PATH` in your cron. You either set the `PATH` env var correctly or use the absolute path to `python`

Comment: Shouldn't activating the virtualenv take care of python path?

Comment: Probably `source` is failing, so `&&` short circuits. Try redirecting stderr/out to a file from the first `source`. You should see the error. (aside, this is one of the nice things about using systemd timers instead of cron, debugging is way easier)

Comment: @ChrisDown let me try that and check the output

Comment: @ChrisDown yeah you are right. The source command itself is failing.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, then cron's default shell `/bin/sh` is `dash` - which doesn't support the `source` synonym for `.`

Comment: @steeldriver got it. I added SHELL=/bin/bash at the beginning of the crontab file, to make it use the bash shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that `source` is failing, so `&&` short circuits. Try redirecting stderr/out to a file from the first `source` and you should see the error.

If `trial.py` ran at all, you should at least see `trial.log` created by the shell. The fact that it's not created suggests that this code was never run.